# Heroku - Server Error (500) - Not Static - DEBUG = False

Tags: django, heroku, static, http-status-code-500

On my Django website, I am working on getting the final bugs out and I am running into an error. I finally got my static files to host using Whitenoise and they are hosting fine on the local server when DEBUG = True or False and they are hosting fine on in production on Heroku when DEBUG = True. I know that you can get a lot of the same 500 errors when static files are being hosted locally but I don't believe that I am getting these 500 errors from my static files anymore. I have been looking at the Heroku logs after the 500 errors come up and I haven't been able to narrow down the problem. I am hoping that someone can help me answer the following question. **Why am I receiving Server Error (500) in Heroku when DEBUG = False.** Thanks in advance!!

settings.py:

```
import django_heroku
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django_quill import quill
from inspect_list.security import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BAS_DIR, 'media')
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p',]

#Media_URL = '/signup/front_page/sheets/'


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
#SECRET_KEY = 'HERE BUT SECURED IN A DIFFERENT FILE'


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']



EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    #'django_quill',
    #'tinymce',
    #'ckeditor',

    #'django_extensions',

    'storages',
    #'django-storages',

    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'inspect_list.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inspect_list.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

#AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'HERE BUT SECURED IN A DIFFERENT FILE'
#AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'HERE BUT SECURED IN A DIFFERENT FILE'
#AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'HERE BUT SECURED IN A DIFFERENT FILE'






STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static\css"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static\png"),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'











# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Cancun'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.CustomUser'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'front_page'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Heroku logs after/during crash:

```
2022-01-25T23:23:54.761539+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Cycling
2022-01-25T23:23:54.763869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-01-25T23:23:55.528301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-25T23:23:55.575381+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 18:23:55 -0500] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-01-25T23:23:55.575420+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 18:23:55 -0500] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-01-25T23:23:55.575644+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 23:23:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2022-01-25T23:23:55.877348+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 23:23:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-01-25T23:23:56.030602+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-01-25T23:24:04.349710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn inspect_list.wsgi`
2022-01-25T23:24:07.015977+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 23:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2022-01-25T23:24:07.016550+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 23:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:31763 (4)
2022-01-25T23:24:07.016607+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 23:24:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-01-25T23:24:07.029604+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 23:24:07 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-01-25T23:24:07.035577+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 23:24:07 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-01-25T23:24:07.144830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-26T02:22:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user hertelrussell@gmail.com
2022-01-26T02:23:30.066094+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f8da68d4 by user hertelrussell@gmail.com
2022-01-26T02:23:30.066094+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user hertelrussell@gmail.com
2022-01-26T02:23:30.508122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2022-01-26T02:23:30.510439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-01-26T02:23:31.291106+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-01-26T02:23:31.359724+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-26 02:23:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2022-01-26T02:23:31.359770+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 21:23:31 -0500] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-01-26T02:23:31.359946+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-25 21:23:31 -0500] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-01-26T02:23:31.560349+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-26 02:23:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-01-26T02:23:31.689706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-01-26T02:23:37.801350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn inspect_list.wsgi`
2022-01-26T02:23:39.128851+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-26 02:23:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2022-01-26T02:23:39.129142+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-26 02:23:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:23794 (4)
2022-01-26T02:23:39.129184+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-26 02:23:39 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-01-26T02:23:39.132176+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-26 02:23:39 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-01-26T02:23:39.215725+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-26 02:23:39 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-01-26T02:23:39.465823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-26T02:23:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-26T02:24:08.963897+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by user hertelrussell@gmail.com
2022-01-26T02:24:16.568780+00:00 heroku[run.4108]: Awaiting client
2022-01-26T02:24:16.604968+00:00 heroku[run.4108]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2022-01-26T02:24:16.656274+00:00 heroku[run.4108]: State changed from starting to up
2022-01-26T02:24:22.705099+00:00 heroku[run.4108]: Process exited with status 0
2022-01-26T02:24:22.785557+00:00 heroku[run.4108]: State changed from up to complete
2022-01-26T02:24:33.874342+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/front_page/sheets/" host=www.scanspectt.com request_id=6a50b650-4db9-4871-b5c6-971046845b42 fwd="71.232.82.43" dyno=web.1 connect=
0ms service=656ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2022-01-26T02:24:33.874653+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.30.71 - - [25/Jan/2022:21:24:33 -0500] "GET /front_page/sheets/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://www.scanspectt.com/front_page/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; W
in64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
2022-01-26T02:24:34.092456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.scanspectt.com request_id=8d424c47-e115-4bc5-b8c2-02fab0ccf8b9 fwd="71.232.82.43" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms ser
vice=4ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2022-01-26T02:24:34.092793+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.30.71 - - [25/Jan/2022:21:24:34 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://www.scanspectt.com/front_page/sheets/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; W
in64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
2022-01-26T02:35:00.723677+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.18.187 - - [25/Jan/2022:21:35:00 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome
/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
2022-01-26T02:35:00.724441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.scanspectt.com request_id=ec7e2fb5-959d-4f75-af2e-d1faeac1492e fwd="42.83.147.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms s
tatus=500 bytes=410 protocol=http
```

Comment: First, use their postgresql database and not a sqlite3... your sqlite might be deleted. Try to install sentry to get more info about your errors: https://sentry.io

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I fixed it. I didn't switch my database over but I deleted all my migrations and my database reran manage.py makemigrations and migrate and then rebuilt the whole website through Heroku.